# MySQL query inserts "0" for all column values

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have an HTML form with 5 textboxes. Upon the click of the submit button, the form is submitted to a page called "admin.php"

**admin.php**

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/inc/init.php');
$reference_key = $_POST['reference_key'];
$success = false;
switch ($reference_key)
{
    case 0: break;
    case 2: {
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $time = $_POST['time'];
        $gym = $_POST['gym'];
        $home = $_POST['home'];
        $away = $_POST['away'];
        $success = "";
        try {
            newGame($db7, $date, $time, $gym, $home, $away);
            $success="index.php";
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            $success="/404";
        }
        //header("Location: " . $success);
    } break;
    default: break;
}

function newGame($db, $date, $time, $gym, $home, $away)
{
    $db->addGameToSchedule($date, $time, $gym, $home, $away);
}
?>
```

When the form is submitted, a reference key is passed. The value of the reference key is "2" and as you can see in the code above for admin.php, a specific set of code is executed when the key is 2. As pointed out in the code, function `newGame` is executed, which in turn calls the function `addGameToSchedule`.

addGameToSchedule function:

```
public function addGameToSchedule($date, $time, $gym, $home, $away) {
    try {
        print "Date: " . $date . "\nTime: " . $time . "\nGym: " . $gym . "\nHome: " . $home . "\nAway: " . $away;
        $sth = $this -> db -> prepare("INSERT INTO schedule (date, time, gym, home, away) VALUES (':date', ':time', ':gym', ':home', ':away')");
        $sth -> execute(array(':date' => $date, ':time' => $time, ':gym' => $gym, ':home' => $home, ':away' => $away));
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        header('Location: /404');
    }
}
```

The `print` statement at the top of the function is to check if the values are being passed correctly. When the code is executed, the print statement correctly prints the information I entered. However, when I check the database for the new row of values, I only see "0" for the 5 columns that I am inserting in.

What am I doing wrong? Please let me know if I need to add more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't put parameter placeholders inside quotes. Inside quotes, any literal string containing no digits is converted to 0. Just like `SELECT 1 + 'abc'` returns 1+0 or 1.

Do this instead:

```
$sth = $this -> db -> prepare("INSERT INTO schedule (date, time, gym, home, away)
    VALUES (:date, :time, :gym, :home, :away)");
```

---

Re comment from @redolent:

Try this:

```
mysql> SELECT ':date' AS value;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| :date |
+-------+
```

The quoted string is a literal, not a parameter placeholder. In that example, it is just a string literal.

If we force it to be interpreted as a number:

```
mysql> SELECT 0 + ':date' AS value;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.04 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: ':date'
```

If we force it to be interpreted as a date:

```
mysql> SELECT DATE(':date') AS value;
+-------+
| value |
+-------+
| NULL  |
+-------+
1 row in set, 1 warning (0.35 sec)

Warning (Code 1292): Incorrect datetime value: ':date'
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks for the explanation about why it gets converted to 0. :)  I appreciate it!

Comment: Are you saying that with quotes, `':date'` is converted to `'0'`? Or is it converted to the literal `':date'` instead of e.g., `'2014-01-01'`?

Comment: @redolent, see examples above.